# Uncaught ReferenceError for JavaScript elements while opening saved html page using chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to store HTML page and associated JavaScripts in such a way that when I open it locally using any browser, the page gets loaded in the browser without any Uncaught ReferenceError.

For example, when I save the page using chrome by right click and save as, the HTML page and associated resources of the page gets downloaded and saved to a local directory and all the references in HTML point to that local resource directory. However, if I open the HTML page in chrome, in the console it displays Uncaught ReferenceError for various JavaScript elements.

I have tried to load the page using Django, kept HTML page in the template directory and change the page to load the resources from static/js directory.
Still getting the same error while accessing the URL through the browser.

For example I have manually saved in.yahoo.com page as yahoo.html and yahoo_resource_dir.

Kept yahoo HTML is Django project like below,

- TestPortal

  - TestApp

    - templates

      - yahoo.html
    - static

      - yahoo_resource_dir

Views.py

```
def malurl(request):
    html = TemplateResponse(request, "yahoo.html")
    return HttpResponse(html.render())
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [path('malicious/', malurl)]
```

html page:

```
{%load static%}
<Other HTML elements>
<script ref={% static 'yahoo_resource_dir/TestJavaScript.js' %}>
```

Expected Result: Page should get open with all the dependent resource kept in a resource directory with no JavaScript exception like Uncaught ReferenceError.

Comment: Download all of the resources manually then, one by one. Mirror the directory structure locally.

Comment: I have manually saved the page using Chrome (Right click -> Save As). This saves html page and its associated resources locally.
Getting same error (Uncaught ReferenceError), when I am opening the saved html page using Chrome.